# Random set of images using php

Tags: php, random

I have this code that I've been using to select one random image. Now I need to select four random images.

I've tried to modify the code and it does work but I can't figure out a way to prevent the same images appearing twice. My knowledge of php is basic at best.

Can anyone shed any light please?

Thanks

my code

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = '/_/images/banners/';

function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {

            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 );
    $num = array_rand($ar);
    return $ar[$num];
}

$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

$imgA = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
$imgB = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
$imgC = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
$imgD = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $path . $imgA ?>" alt="<?php echo ucfirst(preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imgA)) . ' Logo'; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $path . $imgB ?>" alt="<?php echo ucfirst(preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imgB)) . ' Logo'; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $path . $imgC ?>" alt="<?php echo ucfirst(preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imgC)) . ' Logo'; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $path . $imgD ?>" alt="<?php echo ucfirst(preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imgD)) . ' Logo'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just grab all files out of the directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). After this I filter the array with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and only grab the files which matches to the array: `["gif", "jpg", "png"]`. I do this with a simple [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) check where I get the extension of the file with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and take it in lowercase with [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

To get now random images I just [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and take X images from the array start with [`array_silce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

At the end I just simple print all images.

```
<?php

    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path = '/_/images/banners/';
    $random = 4;

    $images = array_filter(glob($root . $path . "*.*"), function($v){
        return in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), ["gif", "jpg", "png"]);
    });

    shuffle($images);
    $randomImages = array_slice($images, 0, $random);

    foreach($randomImages as $v)
        echo "<img src='" . $v . "' alt='" . ucfirst(pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_FILENAME)) . " Logo'>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate it. Thats working but I'm getting the full path from my macs HD rather than the root of my server. How would I change it to stop that and just get the path from the server root?

Comment: @Ricky55 You could change this: `glob($root . $path . "*.*")`, to `glob("path from the directory where this file is to images/" . "*.*")`

Comment: Thanks mate. Really appreciate your help. Works like a charm. I'd spent ages trying to get my feeble mind around this before asking you experts.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain mate but is there anyway to get that root working? If I change my path to /_/images/banners/ without root it doesn't work just like an include wouldn't. Is there a way to make that root just be the root of my local server?

Comment: Got it working by replacing the final echo with: echo "<img src='" . substr($v, strlen($root)) . "' alt='" . ucfirst(pathinfo($v, PATHINFO_FILENAME)) . " Logo'>";

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to obtain a list of the desired number of random keys, not just one. The second argument specifies how many keys should be returned:

```
<?php

$randomKeys = array_rand($imgList, 4);

foreach($randomKeys as $key) {
    echo '<img src="' . $path . $imgList[$key] . '" alt="' . ucfirst(preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imgList[$key])) . ' Logo">';
}
```

Comment: Well this won't work! Imagine a image is in `/var/www/xy/images/image.jpg` now your src attr. will hold `image.jpg` and not the full path

Comment: @Rizier123: Thanks! I left out `$path` that is in OP's code.